# Once a jQuery object is initiated, how to access it after?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jwizard

Once jQuery object has been created to an element, how can I access it? For instance, the following object is being created using the jWizard jQuery, but I need to call some functions on this object, but I have no idea where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$("#wizard").jWizard({
        menuEnable: true,
        counter: {enable: true},
        effects: {enable: true},
        buttons: {
            cancelHide: false,
            cancelType: "button", 
            finishType: "submit", 
            cancelText: "Cancel", 
            previousText: "Back",
            nextText: "Next", 
            finishText: "Submit"
        }
    });
```

Source:
http://www.dbarnes.info/jWizard/ (jWizard jQuery plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign it to a variable:

```
my_wizard = $("#wizard").jWizard({
    menuEnable: true,
    counter: {enable: true},
    effects: {enable: true},
    buttons: {
        cancelHide: false,
        cancelType: "button", 
        finishType: "submit", 
        cancelText: "Cancel", 
        previousText: "Back",
        nextText: "Next", 
        finishText: "Submit"
    }
});
```